# Access current UserId and TenantId with OData controller

Tags: odata, aspnetboilerplate

I've added Odata to my asp.net core boilerplate project as per the documentation:https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/OData-AspNetCore-Integration

How do I access the Current TenantId and UserId within the AbpODataEntityController?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this sample code.

```cs
public class MyODataController : Abp.AspNetCore.OData.Controllers.AbpODataEntityController<User, long>, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly UserManager _userManager;

    public MyODataController(IRepository<User, long> repository, UserManager userManager) : base(repository)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public long? GetCurrentUserId()
    {
        return _userManager.AbpSession.UserId;
    }

    public int? GetCurrentTenantId()
    {
        return _userManager.AbpSession.TenantId;
    }
}
```

PS: don't forget to inherit from ITransientDependency so that it registers to dependency service.

Comment: Thanks, I've done as you suggested, but _userManager.AbpSession.UserId & _userManager.AbpSession.TenantId are both returning null.

I've noticed I can make odata calls via the browser without any token authentication, is there something I need to do to make odata calls authenticate with a valid user?

Comment: @DLedge Add [`[AbpMvcAuthorize]` attribute](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Authorization#using-abpauthorize-attribute) to your controller.