# How to SignIn using AbpODataEntityController

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

In this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129387/access-current-userid-and-tenantid-with-odata-controller/51135987), It was asked how to get current UserId with odata controller.
There are 2 methods. In these methods AbpSession was used.One of them is:

```
 public long? GetCurrentUserId()
    {
       return _userManager.AbpSession.UserId;
    }
```

By using that snippet I could not get the UserId. It was always null. Before calling 'GetCurrentUserId' method I have  signed in by using Web.Mvc application. But UserId is always null. My controller is:

```
 //[AbpMvcAuthorize]

public class UsersController : AbpODataEntityController<User,long>, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly UserManager _userManager;





    public UsersController(IRepository<User, long> repository, UserManager userManager) : base(repository)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }




    public long? GetCurrentUserId()
    {
       //var test= _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.EmailAddress;
        var bak= _userManager.AbpSession.UserId;
        return _userManager.AbpSession.UserId;
    }

    public int? GetCurrentTenantId()
    {
        return _userManager.AbpSession.TenantId;
    }


}
```

and StartUp in Web.Host project:

```
builder.EntityType<User>().Collection 
                .Function("GetCurrentUserId")
                .Returns<long>();
```

I should also say that, if I use '[AbpMvcAuthorize]' attribute in my odata controller, my odata result is

> {"result":null,"targetUrl":null,"success":false,"error":{"code":0,"message":"Current user did not login to the application!","details":null,"validationErrors":null},"unAuthorizedRequest":true,"__abp":true}

even if I have logged in Web.Mvc application. It says

> Current user did not login to the application!

Should I Signin on host application somehow?

Because of some security reasons, My appSettings file in Web.Mvc application should not contain database connection strings. Each user have to sign in using remote services. My main problem is I don't know how to signin the user by using odata or classical  webapi methods.

This is StartUp class located in Web.Host application

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.Internal;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Castle.Facilities.Logging;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using Abp.AspNetCore;
using Abp.AspNetCore.OData.Configuration;
using Abp.Castle.Logging.Log4Net;
using Abp.Extensions;
using TSE.DergiAbone.Configuration;
using TSE.DergiAbone.Identity;

using Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using TSE.DergiAbone.Authorization.Users;
using TSE.DergiAbone.Cities;
using TSE.DergiAbone.Countries;
using TSE.DergiAbone.Districts;
using TSE.DergiAbone.Neighborhoods;
using TSE.DergiAbone.Towns;

namespace TSE.DergiAbone.Web.Host.Startup
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private const string _defaultCorsPolicyName = "localhost";

        private readonly IConfigurationRoot _appConfiguration;

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            _appConfiguration = env.GetAppConfiguration();
        }

        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // MVC
            //services.AddMvc(
            //    options => options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory(_defaultCorsPolicyName))
            //);

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory(_defaultCorsPolicyName));
                options.Filters.Add<ResultFilter>();
            }).AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore); 

            IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);
            AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration);

            services.AddSignalR();

            // Configure CORS for angular2 UI
            services.AddCors(
                options => options.AddPolicy(
                    _defaultCorsPolicyName,
                    builder => builder
                        .WithOrigins(
                            // App:CorsOrigins in appsettings.json can contain more than one address separated by comma.
                            _appConfiguration["App:CorsOrigins"]
                                .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                .Select(o => o.RemovePostFix("/"))
                                .ToArray()
                        )
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                )
            );

            // Swagger - Enable this line and the related lines in Configure method to enable swagger UI
            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "DergiAbone API", Version = "v1" });
                options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) => true);

                // Define the BearerAuth scheme that's in use
                options.AddSecurityDefinition("bearerAuth", new ApiKeyScheme()
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = "header",
                    Type = "apiKey"
                });
            });


            services.AddOData();

            // Workaround: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1177
            services.AddMvcCore(options =>
            {
                foreach (var outputFormatter in options.OutputFormatters.OfType<ODataOutputFormatter>().Where(_ => _.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
                {
                    outputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
                }
                foreach (var inputFormatter in options.InputFormatters.OfType<ODataInputFormatter>().Where(_ => _.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
                {
                    inputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
                }
            });



            // Configure Abp and Dependency Injection
            return services.AddAbp<DergiAboneWebHostModule>(
                // Configure Log4Net logging
                options => options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
                    f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
                )
            );
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseAbp(options => { options.UseAbpRequestLocalization = false; }); // Initializes ABP framework.

            app.UseCors(_defaultCorsPolicyName); // Enable CORS!

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAbpRequestLocalization();


            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<AbpCommonHub>("/signalr");
            });


            app.UseOData(builder =>
            {
                builder.EntitySet<Abone.Abone>("Abones").EntityType.Expand().Count().Filter().OrderBy().Page();
                builder.EntitySet<Abonelik.Abonelik>("Aboneliks").EntityType.Count().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Page();
                builder.EntitySet<Test.Test>("Tests").EntityType.Count().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Page();
                builder.EntitySet<Country>("Countries").EntityType.Count().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Page();
                builder.EntitySet<City>("Cities").EntityType.Count().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Page();
                builder.EntitySet<Town>("Towns").EntityType.Count().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Page().Select();
                builder.EntitySet<District>("Districts").EntityType.Count().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Page();
                builder.EntitySet<Neighborhood>("Neighborhoods").EntityType.Count().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Page();
                builder.EntitySet<SinifDergi.SinifDergi>("DergiSinifs").EntityType.Count().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Page().Select();
                builder.EntitySet<User>("Users").EntityType.Count().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Page().Select();

                //Action ekleme

                //ODataModelBuilder builderr = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
                //builderr.EntitySet<Test.Test>("Products");


                //builderr.Namespace = "ProductService";
                //builderr.EntityType<Test.Test>()
                //    .Action("Rate")
                //    .Parameter<int>("Rating");
                //builder.EntitySet<Town>("Towns").EntityType.Action("Test").Parameter<string>("TestValue");
                //builder.EntitySet<Town>("Towns").EntityType.Action("Test");

                builder.EntityType<Town>().Collection
                    .Function("Test")
                    .Returns<string>();
                //.Parameter<string>("param");

                builder.EntityType<Town>().Collection//.Action("stringTest")
                    .Function("stringTest")
                    .Returns<IActionResult>()
                .Parameter<string>("param");



                builder.EntityType<Town>().Collection//.Action("stringTest")
                    .Function("GetTownsByCityId")
                    .Returns<IActionResult>()
                    .Parameter<int>("cityID");


                builder.EntityType<User>().Collection //.Action("stringTest")
                    .Function("GetCurrentUserId")
                    .Returns<long>();
                //.Parameter<int>("cityID");

                builder.EntityType<Abone.Abone>().Collection//.Action("stringTest")
                    .Function("TCKimlikNoBelirliDergiAboneligiIcinDahaOnceKullanilmisMi")
                    .Returns<bool>()
                    .Parameter<string>("TCKimlikNo");


            });

            // Return IQueryable from controllers
            app.UseUnitOfWork(options =>
            {
                options.Filter = httpContext =>
                {
                    return httpContext.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/odata");
                };
            });


            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {

                routes.MapODataServiceRoute(app);

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "defaultWithArea",
                    template: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
            app.UseSwagger();
            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint(_appConfiguration["App:ServerRootAddress"].EnsureEndsWith('/') + "swagger/v1/swagger.json", "DergiAbone API V1");
                options.IndexStream = () => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetManifestResourceStream("TSE.DergiAbone.Web.Host.wwwroot.swagger.ui.index.html");
            }); // URL: /swagger
        }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me about the proper way of signing the user in by using remote services? Thank you.

I am calling GetCurrentUserId() method in Web.Core project in a custom controller caalled UsersController. And the content of this controller is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Abp.AspNetCore.OData.Controllers;
using Abp.Dependency;
using Abp.Domain.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TSE.DergiAbone.Authorization.Users;
using TSE.DergiAbone.Countries;
using TSE.DergiAbone.Towns;
namespace TSE.DergiAbone.Web.Host.Controllers
{
    //[EnableQueryWithSearch]
    [AbpMvcAuthorize]

    public class UsersController : AbpODataEntityController<User,long>, ITransientDependency
    {
        private readonly UserManager _userManager;





        public UsersController(IRepository<User, long> repository, UserManager userManager) : base(repository)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }




        public long? GetCurrentUserId()
        {
           //var test= _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.EmailAddress;
            var bak= _userManager.AbpSession.UserId;
            return _userManager.AbpSession.UserId;
        }

        public int? GetCurrentTenantId()
        {
            return _userManager.AbpSession.TenantId;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: show your startup class

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu I've edited my question and added StartUp class located in Web.Host application

Comment: your startup looks OK. show where do you call `GetCurrentUserId()` method. Maybe you did not register a project as an ABP module!

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu I've edited and added the controller containing GetCurrentUserId() method. And please kindly notice that, I need to sign in to application only using remote services, classical web api or  webapi odata. Boss would not like to see connection string in config file. I should manage registration, sign in operations and every data transfer  via remote services. I can not achieve signing in to app via remote services. I could not even successfully get the userid from services ..sadness.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use `IAbpSession`

```
public class UsersController : AbpODataEntityController<User,long>, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IAbpSession  _abpSession;

    public UsersController(
        IRepository<User, long> repository, 
        UserManager userManager, 
        IAbpSession abpSession
    ) : base(repository)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _abpSession = abpSession;
    }

    public long? GetCurrentUserId()
    {       
        return _abpSession.GetUserId();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlperEbicioglu    Thank you for your answer. But no use.. It says :{"result":null,"targetUrl":null,"success":false,"error":{"code":0,"message":"Current user did not login to the application!","details":null,"validationErrors":null},"unAuthorizedRequest":true,"__abp":true} But I have logged in in Web.Mvc application

Comment: this message says, you didn't authenticate successfully. if you have logged in your MVC application, then check that the authentication cookie is being sent to the server with your request. if you don't know which is the authentication cookie, open your mvc application and capture the request & response in Chrome. then compare the valid and working cookies with your Odata request.

Comment: This is irrelevant..I've downloaded 3 instances of ABP and installed three different machines from scratch. If you even logged in from Web.Mvc application, Application Services and Web.Core applications could not know who you are if you put   [AbpMvcAuthorize] attribute into the beginning of controller. And if you don't, UserId in AbpSession always null. So, you mean if someone logged in on Web.Mvc application then these apps above should know who logged in certainly?  I need to authenticate an login users  into the system using remote services. Isn't there a sample code?